# Show that there exists an integer $m \ge 1$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}] \subseteq R$ and $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a finite extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $R$ be a subring of $K$ which is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring, in other words $R = \mathbb{Z}[ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]$ for elements $\alpha_k \in K$. Show that there exists an integer $m \ge 1$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}] \subseteq R$ and $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$.

My start at a solution:

Let $\mu_k$ be the monic minimal polynomial of $\alpha_k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. For each $\mu_k$ let $m_k$ be the least common denominator for the coefficients of $\mu_k$. Let $m$ be the least common multiple of the $m_k$.

Let $L$ be the Galois closure of $K$. 
Let $S$ be the Galois closure of $R$, that is,
 $S = \mathbb{Z}[\text{all the roots of the $u_k$}]$. Then $R$ is a subring of $S$.

The action of $\mathrm{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ on $S$ is an automorphism that fixes $S \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Thus, by the link below, if $S \cap \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$ then $S$ is integrable over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$ which implies that $R$ is also.

- http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Ring_is_integral_extension_of_fixed-point_subring_under_finite_automorphism_group

Then if we can show that $\frac{1}{m} \in R$ this implies that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}] \subseteq R \subseteq S$. Thus it suffices to show two things:

1. $\frac{1}{m} \in R$
2. $S \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$

I'm not sure how to prove either of these two things. Or is there another way I should be proving this?

---

Second attempt at a solution:

Let $\mu_k$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the smallest integer such that $\alpha_k$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$ is the least common denominator of the coefficients of $\mu_k$; call this $m_k$.

(In any smaller ring the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be written with a monic leading coefficient and so $\alpha_k$ fails to be integral over any smaller ring.)

Let $m$ be the least common multiple of the $m_k$. Since sums and products of integral elements are integral then $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$. What remains to be shown is one thing

$\frac{1}{m} \in R$.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you know how to argue by clearing denominators? Notice that every element of $K$ is integral over $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$ for some non-zero $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since sums and products of integral elements are integral then $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$ if and only if each $\alpha_k$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$.
Then $\mu_k$ is a monic polynomial for $\alpha_k$ over $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$ therefore $\alpha_k$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$ and so $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$.
Then I need only show that $1/m \in R$. But how do I show this?

Comment: Do you undrstand now what I want to say when you found an answer?